# Bug: Negative zero score?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

I thought the Red color was used to indicate a negative score.  But then I see this:

[image]

It seems to me that the selection for the Red color is a `score > 0? Green : Red` when it should be `score >= 0 ? Green : Red`

Since zero is, ya know, not a negative number.

Answer (score 14):

The choice is that it can either be **Green** or **Red**.  The solution would be to either make it **Green** or...

### Make zero black!

Since it's neither positive nor negative, it shouldn't be green or red, but black.

`score == 0 ? black : score > 0 ? green : red;`

Comment: A *third* color? You're a madman

Comment: @Richard - Do you understand what you asking for here? The *algorithms* needed? Good-luck, and Godspeed.

Comment: I know!  The thousands of manhours required! Maybe if we got an infinite amount of monkeys...

Comment: This will happen in the next build, for sites with the new reputation system rolled out (meta only for the moment, everywhere else soon).

Answer (score 3):

Zero is not negative or positive; it is neutral. That's likely why it is labelled as negative since you got nothing positive.

Comment: In IEEE floating points there is a positive and a negative zero! :-) (this comment is totally useless, but this is a meta-board of the biggest programming board around, so it's ok enough to point it, I think)

Comment: @xanatos Haha that is true. +1!

Comment: Using your flawless logic, I got nothing *negative* either.

Comment: @Richard I think you took my answer the wrong way there.

Comment: @SimonSheehan: You're right.  +0 to you.