# Inconsistent display of daily reputation in profile rep tab

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug: Negative zero score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110035/bug-negative-zero-score)

Looking at the reputation tab of my [main profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593627/george-duckett?tab=reputation), I see that some days are missing. Presumably because I've not gained or lost any reputation.

[image: November, November, Remember November]

Given the above, I'm interested in why November the 5th appears (showing zero reputation change). I'm aware of the text,

> Reputation on deleted posts and votes is not shown here

So I guess that's the explanation. However, it seems a contradiction that although "they're not shown here", the day is shown.

Should the day I got zero points not show up / be hidden?

<sup>I don't like the red color shown on that day in with all my nice green ones.</sup>

Comment: Also, is there a script or something where i can easily screengrab (from the site), crop and post (on Windows 7)? I already have the one to add my own unicorns, but that requires an already uploaded image.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110035/bug-negative-zero-score

Comment: I think this can happen if you lose rep for some reason (downvote an answer or get a post downvoted), and later that rep is restored by reversing the action that lost it.